# How to to break down nested sequences into its components

Tags: premiere, audio

I have a subsequence (or nested sequence), and I'm using only part of it a in a larger sequence. Is there any good way to break it down into its components so it will be cut exactly right? (I'm not using the entire nested sequence, just a part of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out minutes after posting. Like this:

1. Enable the [Nest Source Sequence option](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/edit-sequences-loaded-source-monitor.html).
2. Put marker on the beginning frame of nested sequence. double click to go inside it (it will put the marker on the right spot), and then do Ctrl+C.
3. Go back to the main sequence, and drag the subsequence\nested sequence from the source monitor. You'll get the individual parts from the nested sequence that match the trimmed version you already have.

Hope this helps anyone.

**P.S**

Adobe, can you please streamline this? I mean, it's ridiculous

Comment: See http://video.stackexchange.com/q/18550/1871